# Kafka ACLs - unable to describe group or view offsets in Kafka Tool after setting ACLs

Tags: apache-kafka

Using Kafka version 1.1
I´ve enabled SASL on one port for clients while moving the interbroker communication to other port with PLAINTEXT.
Problem is that I am having troubles discovering info about topic and group after setting ACLs for clients as described below.

**server.properties** - added entries below
`allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=true
super.users=User:admin (user included in jaas config file)`

Created topic "testavro" and set the ACLs for one of the topics in a following way:
    `kafka-acls --authorizer kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --allow-principal User:cons --consumer --topic testavro --group testavroCons`

and
`kafka-acls --authorizer kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --allow-principal User:prod --producer --topic testavro`

Now producing and consuming works just fine.
But when I try to use kafka-consumer-group tool to describe the testavroCons group, I will get follwing message:
*Error: Executing consumer group command failed due to Not authorized to access group: Group authorization failed.*

Simmilar when I try to use Kafka Tool to read offsets for the specified consumer group testavroCons. I don see them. I dont even see the testavro topic in the list now.

What other privileges are needed in this case? I understand that its the ACL issue but I want to avoid global rules. Is there some setting on Zookeeper or between Zookeeper and brokers missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things which were needed.
(apart from good comprehension of security around client-server roles and authentication vs authorization!)

**First** add the user to the SASL configuration. Both for the broker and client.
(solving the authentication part)
**Second** was add new user as SuperUser to Kafka broker server.properties.
(solving the authorization part)

**Details**(just one entry as an example):
*jaas configuration* on broker side

```
 KafkaServer {
     org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
     user_testuser="testuser_password";
 };
```

*jaas configuration* "client" side

```
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
username=\"testuser\" password=\"testuser_password\";
```

*server.properties*

```
super.users=User:testuser
```

Now when i run
(where kafka_tools_jaas.conf contains jaas configuration for client side)
It work well.

```
kafka-consumer-groups --describe --group testavroCons --bootstrap-server server:port --command-config /tmp/kafka_tools_jaas.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

For user `u` to be able to describe a group `g` that consumes from topic `t` these ACLs permissions are required:

```
bin/kafka-acls.sh --authorizer kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --allow-principal User:u --operation Describe --group g
bin/kafka-acls.sh --authorizer kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --allow-principal User:u --operation Describe --topic t
```

[Reference](https://developer.ibm.com/code/howtos/kafka-authn-authz)

Comment: Thanks a lot for response. I found out that my comprehension of the client-server roles and authentication vs authorization in Kafka environment wasn´t sufficient as I stated in my other answer.